# Best way to a call server side route without using front end Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route in the backend that I would like to call every X amount of time. Right now I am using ajax to make the call from a set interval function on the client side:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api'
    })
        .done(function() {})
        .fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, 60000);
```

My route:

```
router.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('api called')
});
```

The problem is that this only works when someone has the application opened in their browser. What would be the best way to make such a call in the backend without relying on the front end?

Comment: You can either pay a service for this, or you could create your own nodejs script with `node-fetch` and use `fetch` to call your api

Comment: Why would you ever need such a thing?) Just curious)

Comment: it's basically a route that goes through all my users and updates whether their training are still valid or have expired @NikitaMazur

Comment: You can just create a cronjob on your server, no need for route here @EmilC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an internal call from the server itself, rather than from within a client. It would follow exactly the same logic (with the interval), but the code would be on the backend :)

Also if you'd like it a bit more well defined, you could use something like [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron):

```js
cron.schedule('*/2 * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every two minutes');
});
```